# How to merge four ImageView into single and apply zoom-in and zoom-out on merged view in android?

Tags: android, xml, android-layout

I have four Imageview in the layout and I want to merge them all and after that I want to apply zoom-in and zoom-out feature on the complete view.
How can I achieve this functionality ?

Answer (score 0):

Conceptually what you are trying to achieve does not make sense to me,
Anyway I'll Give you my Idea if i was in need of what you are trying to achieve

Create a `GridLayout` or any other layout as a platform for the four ImageViews `Img1,Img2,Img3 and Img4`

Now after you created and loaded the Images into the ImageViews, On a button press or something call the `getDrawingCache()` on the `GridLayout` You will get a bitmap object.

use this bitmap object and set this bitmap to another `ImageView` with zoom controlls called `zoomView` and you are done(Hide the other 4 imageViews if required)

[Refer this if you want to find how to add zoom controls to ImageView](http://www.zdnet.com/article/how-to-use-multi-touch-in-android-2-part-6-implementing-the-pinch-zoom-gesture/)